# Angular 2 Full calendar: How to change the events property

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am using [Full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/),

code

```
ngOnInit() {
        
        this.calendarOptions = {
            height: '1000',
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            header:
            {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,listYear',
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-01-01',
            editable: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm A',
            eventLimit: true,
            //eventColor: '#ECFCD8',


            events: (start, end, title, callback) => {
                
                this.calenderservice.getExamCandidateById(this.value)
                    .subscribe(response => {
                        callback(response),
                            this.modalData = response.Items
                        this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.modalData)
                        console.log(this.modalData);
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            }
}
```

Here i am calling services on events and getting response from server which contain start,end,title and rendering onto fullcalendar  `this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.modalData)`,now before rendering, i want to change the event title with adding string to that and render the fullcalendar

Please help me,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use the eventDataTransform callback I think: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for answer, i tried, but can you please give some example for to change the title using eventDataTransform

Comment: Just like you change any other JS object property: `eventDataTransform: function( eventData ) { eventData.title = "XYZ"; }`